# Filtering an MDX Set Based on Another Set's Name

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm still new to MDX so I'm not sure if there's an easy way, or a not-so-easy way to do what I'm asking, but here's a vague description of what I'm trying to do for my MDX query. I have two sets, both not directly related in the same hierarchy or cousins, although there may be a "family" call I don't know about that will do what I'm trying to do.

`[Company].[Parent Company].[Parent Company]` retrieves a set of all the members of companies that are parents of a company in the second set.

`[Company].[Company].[Company]` retrieves a set of all the members of companies themselves, including the parents themselves.

I'm trying to filter out the `[C].[C].[C]` set to **NOT** include any instances of a `[Parent Company]` in a MEMBER for my MDX query. I tried some weird stuff with Filter() but kept messing up sets/tuples or getting the wrong kind of data.
 There isn't any grandparent/multi-generational trickery to these sets, there's only two levels to worry about (companies and their potential parents, there may not be any). If the cube was formatted better, it would had been nice if they were in a hierarchy, but that's not the case here.

Example output:

- Members of `[Company].[Parent Company].[ParentCompany]` = {A, C, E}
- Members of `[Company].[Company].[Company]` = {A, B, C, D, E, F, G}

Then I want to get a set that will return the following: {B, D, F, G} and that's it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you list some sample data showing the desired output and what you wish to exclude?

Comment: Just edited the question to include theoretical sets and desired output. Thanks!

Comment: This is going to be pretty challenging, most of the normal MDX functions don't work against the string labels but against the unique names and in this case they will be different since they are coming from different hierarchies.  Are you able to create an actual parent/child hierarchy in your dimension?  If so it would be easy to filter the parents out.

Comment: I recently just set up the hierarchy so I didn't have to do this after all, it seemed easier than banging my head against complicated filter queries and more efficient. However, out of sheer curiosity, I'd like to know how such a thing would be possible if I didn't have access to the cube to change the hierarchy. I figured there would be some kind of filter trick using the Member_Name and not Unique_Name but I never got that far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without using the Member_Name:

```
Exclude([Company].[Company].[Company].Members, Extract([Company].[Company].[Company].Members * [Company].[Parent Company].[Parent Company].Members, [Company].[Company]))
```

or

```
Exclude([Company].[Company].[Company].Members, Exists([Company].[Company].[Company].Members, [Company].[Parent Company].[Parent Company].Members))
```